# continuity of the sort operator

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, continuity, order-statistics, permutation-cycles

here's my question. Let $\mathcal{S}\colon\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be the function that map a real vector into a vector having its components ordered either way, ascending or descending. Is $\mathcal{S}$ continuous? I think that's true and I guess a way to prove that is by using sequences.

Thanks!

Comment: consider $n = 2$, and induction, or suppose it is discontinuous at $(x_1,\ldots x_n)$ and show a contradiction. and prove it is continuous for a **given** norm, for example $\|x\| = \sum_i |x_i|$ and say it is then continuous for any norm as all the norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent